# Did Lincoln ever publicly blame James Buchanan?

Tags: united-states, abraham-lincoln

## Background

Several modern presidents have publicly blamed their predecessor for at least one issue that occurred during their presidency: [Trump](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/03/13/coronavirus-trump-says-i-dont-take-responsibility-at-all-for-lack-of-tests.html), [Obama](https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/the-fix/post/president-obama-and-the-bush-blame-game/2011/08/30/gIQA4n94pJ_blog.html), and [Reagan](https://www.nytimes.com/1977/06/10/archives/reagan-is-critical-of-carter-on-rights-he-accuses-the.html) are some examples. I am unsure of how historians view this behavior...but it does not elicit a positive response from [contemporaries](https://www.politico.com/story/2014/06/barack-obama-iraq-george-w-bush-107885).

Likewise, is there any recorded documents of Lincoln publicly blaming Buchanan for any of the issues he faced?

Why Lincoln: He is consistently ranked among the greatest presidents of all time by historians. I was just curious if him blaming others added to or subtracted from his greatness from a historical perspective.

Why Buchanan: In the examples of Trump, Obama, and Reagan that I cited, the first two frequently blamed directly, or implied, that the problems they faced were their predecessors doing, the third (Reagan) had only one example I could find, but had an apparent way of styling himself in stark contrast to his predecessor. It is this pattern of contrasting/blaming the immediate predecessor that I applied to Lincoln.

Comment: I'll look into this if I get some time, but I think Lincoln's problems he started his term with were really far beyond blaming on one guy.

Answer (score 4):

Unlikely. In the book "Abraham Lincoln. Speeches & Writings 1859-1865", Random House; Library of America, 1989 (which is a comprehensive collection of Lincoln's speeches and letters) James Buchanan is mentioned (by Lincoln) only once, in passing, in a letter to W.H.Wells regarding Lincoln-Douglas debates:

> to support him or Buchanan, is simply to reach the same goal by only slightly different roads.

Comment: Did that volume you cite include Lincoln's speech at a Republican banquet in 1856?  In it he refers to Buchanan by name twice.  References to "The President" are meant to be JB as well I believe as JB has been elected but not yet sworn in yet.  Of course this was before Lincoln was President so does not further the original question. https://teachingamericanhistory.org/library/document/speech-at-a-republican-banquet/

Comment: Ah sorry, I now see that the book you cited covers specific years that were after the 1856 speech.

Comment: @AllInOne: That would presumably be irrelevant to the question, as occurring not only before Lincoln became President, but even before Buchanan became President. Neither was a time traveler to the best of our knowledge.

Comment: @AllInOne  It talks about "the President"'s reaction to Buchanan being elected, naming Buchanan specifically. So "The President" is Pierce.